# RelativeLayout background turn black when started by another activity (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the strangest bug. 
I have a main activity that presents a ViewPager, showing images with footers (RelativeLayout) showing some info.
When this activity is launched from another (a login page containing a webview), the footer background color is black, while it is supposed to be white/grey on pressed.
This leads to unreadable information. I don't change the background color anywhere in code, it is only defined in xml.

The problem only seems to appear on Lollipop, and not even all the time.

The part of the layout that turns black (infoContainer).

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/pager_metadata_container_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white_clickable" >


        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/btn_like"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_like"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pager_metadata_icons_separation_padding"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/pager_metadata_icons_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tint="@android:color/black"
            />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/btn_comment"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_comment"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pager_metadata_icons_separation_padding"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/pager_metadata_icons_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_like"
            android:tint="@android:color/black"
            />
        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/btn_share"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pager_metadata_icons_separation_padding"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/pager_metadata_icons_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_comment"
            android:tint="@android:color/black"
            />


        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/comments"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="@dimen/pager_metadata_text_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingRight="18dp"
            />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/likes"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/comments"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="@dimen/pager_metadata_text_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingRight="18dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the infoContainer, when it is launched by the login page, did you have code to inflate it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937173/how-to-inflate-relativelayout-from-xml (I'm just taking a guess though)

Comment: yes it is inflated. The is the same in both case.

Comment: hmm, to be clear, you're able to see the buttons if you colored them other than black? or do the buttons not show up as well? If they don't show up it could be related to RelativeLayouts android:layout_width="match_parent", I'd check if that value was 0 or not. else I'm not sure. Sorry :/

Comment: Yes the buttons shows up if they are not black, the layout is taking all the space required (I can see it when I dump the hierarchy view). No need to apologize, thx for your help!

Comment: That is odd indeed. the other workaround i can come up with on the top of my head is to explicitly color the background white programmatically in java, possibly in the overriden OnCreate function! Good luck!

Comment: As a matter of fact, when I set the color programmatically as white, it works. But then I loose the press feedback (the layout turns grey on press). If however, I set the background programmatically the same as in my xml, it still turns black...

Comment: try "relaytiveLayout.invalidate();" mayble help you